# service does not load object array

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've made a service class with configuration options.
I'm trying to load array data from `appsettings.json` but, it doesn't pass data to my service.

Here my initializer for service

```
        public static IServiceCollection AddHomePage(
                       this IServiceCollection services,
                       Action<List<HomePageServiceOptions>> setupAction = null)
        {
            if (services == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
            }

            if (setupAction == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(setupAction));
            }
            services.AddTransient<IHomePageService, HomePageService>();
            services.Configure(setupAction);
            return services;
        }
```

I'm fetching data from `appsettings.json` in `Startup.cs` and calling extension above.

```
//here is made list variable to make sure data is not null here
//and I confirmed that it have 1 record. That is what I expected.
var list = Configuration.GetSection("HomePageTemplates").Get<List<HomePageServiceOptions>>();

//here calling extension above with setupAction parameter (list)
services.AddHomePage(o => o = list);
```

Here is my service constructor, where the problem begins with data

```
public class HomePageService : IHomePageService
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;
        private readonly ILogger<HomePageService> logger;
        private readonly List<HomePageServiceOptions> options;

        public HomePageService(
            ApplicationDbContext context, 
            ILogger<HomePageService> logger, 
            Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<List<HomePageServiceOptions>> options)
        {
            if (options is null || options.Value is null)
            {
                logger.LogError("parameter options was null");
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
            }
            this.options = options.Value.ToList();//value count is always 0 here
            this.context = context;
            this.logger = logger;
        }
    }
```

Here is my `HomePageServiceOptions`

```
public class HomePageServiceOptions
    {
        public HomePageServiceOptions()
        {

        }
        
        public DesignType DesignType { get; set; }
        public string ViewPath { get; set; }
        public string PreviewImage { get; set; }
        public List<Section> Sections { get; set; }
        public List<Section> SubSections { get; set; }
    }
    public class Section
    {
        public Section()
        {

        }
        public string InputType { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
public enum DesignType
    {
        Type1,
        Type2,
        Type3,
//...
    }
```

And here my data inside of `appsettings.json`

```
"HomePageTemplates": [
      {
        "ViewPath": "_team.cshtml",
        "PreviewImage": "_team.png",
        "DesignType": "Type1",
        "Sections": [
          {
            "InputType": "text",
            "Description": "Title"
          },
          {
            "InputType": "text",
            "Description": "Title2"
          },
          {
            "InputType": "text",
            "Description": "Extra text"
          },
          {
            "InputType": "text",
            "Description": "Button text"
          }
        ],
        "SubSections": [
          {
            "InputType": "image",
            "Description": "Person image 164x148"
          },
          {
            "InputType": "text",
            "Description": "Person name"
          },
          {
            "InputType": "text",
            "Description": "Person title"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
```

I've tried to change listing type of **options** as array and as `IEnumerable` but, still same result.
Is there I need something special to pass array or list data into services?

here is screenshots about data
`Startup.cs`
[image]

`HomePageService.cs`
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add file appsettings.Development.json  and save in this file all values from appsettings.json
2. In Path add field "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" with "Development". After - restart computer
3. In Startup.cs in ConfigureServices... add

   services.AddOptions();

Comment: I'm able to read data from appsettings.json, I'm just trying to pass that data to the service

Comment: And just tested that array inside appsettingsw.Development.json as you offered. Still same result

Comment: Try services.AddOptions();

Comment: AddOptions helped me about my problem. Thank you! But, seems Step 1 and 2 is not releated.